Parse Base64 Email Attachment in Python
I created an Agent to review emails I forward to it. Emails are sent by AWS SES, stored in S3, and pushed to an SQS queue, which I read in my Python server.
**Unfortunately, I could not extract the base64 attachment from the email. While I manage to read the Sender, Recipient, and other metadata. In the end, attachments is empty array, I cannot find it via Content-Disposition **
Example of the email, this is the last part with the attachment:

Return-Path: <john@gmail.com>
Received: from mail-ua1-f43.google.com (mail-ua1-f43.google.com [209.85.222.43])
 by inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id pukag4ih1cmn9kkv80mbgq76ihqtmn1iegpq37o1
 for review@gmail.app;
 Thu, 19 Sep 2024 04:58:26 +0000 (UTC)
X-SES-Spam-Verdict: PASS
X-SES-Virus-Verdict: PASS
Received-SPF: pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.222.43 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.222.43; envelope-from=john@gmail.com; helo=mail-ua1-f43.google.com;
Authentication-Results: amazonses.com;
 spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.222.43 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.222.43; envelope-from=john@gmail.com; helo=mail-ua1-f43.google.com;
 dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com;
 dmarc=pass header.from=gmail.com;
X-SES-RECEIPT: AEFBQUFBQUFBQUFFZ2JHc0crQjlHelF5VUNDVUU2TUQ3Q2JTTUNxTGJjSm4wc0FHZjhYNc9PQ==
X-SES-DKIM-SIGNATURE: a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; b=PaW0ekScZFtkYj70ZltKs6/F2wVz5u5tbdecPA1MLE2VA9GJs0amXqM7LSCIvElqBkqncHCnv8ihFm+63UNrSfs4udIs0J8487tramL5PFsHweTEjk5m1e26mk6S62jwiH0/jn/yYiubrFxfk38vtXE24eQxGRp+ZM4ADy5ad08=; c=relaxed/simple; s=ug7nbtf4gccmlpwj322ax3p6ow6yfsug; d=amazonses.com; t=1726721906; v=1; bh=bScrS43KllskxOQzi+HJjcjEx0KiD5SVYtuSxG3pO4k=; h=From:To:Cc:Bcc:Subject:Date:Message-ID:MIME-Version:Content-Type:X-SES-RECEIPT;
Received: by mail-ua1-f43.google.com with SMTP id a1e0cc1a2514c-846c5995a6fso123828241.0
        for <review@gmail.app>; Wed, 18 Sep 2024 21:58:26 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20230601; t=1726721905; x=1727326705; darn=gmail.app;
        h=to:subject:message-id:date:from:in-reply-to:references:mime-version
         :from:to:cc:subject:date:message-id:reply-to;
        bh=1EFj7V5N3rGWogN7xvdVR45Df5dw8I9iVhoHHLKwXb8=;
      b=WnqqDF/pk/2qGINGjGq0/2Y6iqc64UX314BpyVYBzAm061fCYECa/rID0/g5k7ubY4
zHFtxGTqui7LbFfmWyW30uHsdHEB8jVXdHEL3ye2QmRyo75r4GlK2QePkyLnzK3UTkVA
         9xSA==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20230601; t=1726721905; x=1727326705;
        h=to:subject:message-id:date:from:in-reply-to:references:mime-version
         :x-gm-message-state:from:to:cc:subject:date:message-id:reply-to;
        bh=1EFj7V5N3rGWogN7xvdVR45Df5dw8I9iVhoHHLKwXb8=;
        b=AIbwVZhgae73QWUp
         4dzA==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOJu0YxvoiAVUcscxADiEKxQhMXaYG7qGSFEJSobz85CPD9HulH36T0v
    VjxeMRSDH9LgyY4639urxmSFD96n/r6HU
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IF94l6O4wxdwbAWB8bUqEzsTjkImbi70jIQzUXeqwL8sM9naZDEQuZ8T/RSuGZzD4PJQXCUSmWFF7nrdWYsxaw=
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6102:e10:b0:498:ef8d:8368 with SMTP id
 ada2fe7eead31-49d4f60e8f6mr15076922137.13.1726721904892; Wed, 18 Sep 2024
 21:58:24 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
References: <SEZPR03MB766.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com>
 <E5084324-CDFB-4236-BCB2@gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <E5084324-CDFB-4236-BCB2@gmail.com>
From: John Doe<john@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2024 12:58:13 +0800
Message-ID: <CAFUY-ktg8M8DB=iyRMpcgU5Ktv41Tpcm+A0RPpzZPHfjNfTqWw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Fwd: From: 61 2 9300 9218, you have received a 3 page fax on:
 291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548 - sample
To: review@gmail.app
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="000000000000c4fbc8062271c50c"

--000000000000c4fbc8062271c50c
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000c4fbc7062271c50a"

--000000000000c4fbc7062271c50a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Forwarderd

---------- Forwarded message ---------
=D0=92=D1=96=D0=B4: Email AI <tech@gmail.com>
Date: =D0=BF=D0=BD, 16 =D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80. 2024=E2=80=AF=D1=80. =D0=BE 21:4=
2
Subject: Fwd: From: 61 2 9300 9218, you have received a 3 page fax on:
291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548 - sample
To: john@gmail.com <john@gmail.com>


Example A

Begin forwarded message:

*From: *Bondi Go <Go.bon@bgmail.com>
*Subject: **FW: From: 61 2 9300 9218, you have received a 3 page fax on:
291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548 - sample*
*Date: *9 September 2024 at 16:55:57 GMT+10
*To: *"tech@gmail.com" <tech@gmail.com>



*From:* Go Receive <receive@Go.com.au>
*Sent:* Wednesday, 31 July 2024 9:36 AM
*To:* Bondi Go <Go.bon@bgmail.com>
*Subject:* From: 61 2 9300 9218, you have received a 3 page fax on:
291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548



Inbound Fax Received
Received at: 31-07-2024-09:35:48
From: 61 2 9300 9218
Remote Fax ID: 13055037548
FaxID: 64235128
On Fax Number: 291693497
Pages: 3
Transmission Result: COMPLETE
Speed: 9600
Connection Time: 113




--=20
*Igor Steblii*

igorsteblii.com

--000000000000c4fbc7062271c50a
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr">Forwarderd<br><br><div class=3D"gmail_quote"><div dir=3D"l=
tr" class=3D"gmail_attr">---------- Forwarded message ---------<br>=D0=92=
=D1=96=D0=B4: <strong class=3D"gmail_sendername" dir=3D"auto">Email AI<=
/strong> <span dir=3D"auto">&lt;<a href=3D"mailto:tech@gmail.com">tech@c=
areaihq.com</a>&gt;</span><br>Date: =D0=BF=D0=BD, 16 =D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80. 20=
24=E2=80=AF=D1=80. =D0=BE 21:42<br>Subject: Fwd: From: 61 2 9300 9218, you =
have received a 3 page fax on: 291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548 - sampl=
e<br>To: <a href=3D"mailto:john@gmail.com">john@gmail.com</=
a> &lt;<a href=3D"mailto:john@gmail.com">john@gmail.com</a>=
&gt;<br></div><br><br>



<div>
<div style=3D"line-break:after-white-space">Example A<br id=3D"m_-798919805=
8068842788x_lineBreakAtBeginningOfMessage">
<div><br>
<blockquote type=3D"cite">
<div>Begin forwarded message:</div>
<br>
<div style=3D"margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left=
:0px">
<span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,san=
s-serif;color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0)"><b>From:
</b></span><span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,He=
lvetica,sans-serif">Bondi Go &lt;<a href=3D"mailto:Go.bon@bjchealth.c=
om.au" target=3D"_blank">Go.bon@bgmail.com</a>&gt;<br>
</span></div>
<div style=3D"margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left=
:0px">
<span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,san=
s-serif;color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0)"><b>Subject:
</b></span><span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,He=
lvetica,sans-serif"><b>FW: From: 61 2 9300 9218, you have received a 3 page=
 fax on: 291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548 - sample</b><br>
</span></div>
<div style=3D"margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left=
:0px">
<span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,san=
s-serif;color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0)"><b>Date:
</b></span><span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,He=
lvetica,sans-serif">9 September 2024 at 16:55:57 GMT+10<br>
</span></div>
<div style=3D"margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left=
:0px">
<span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,san=
s-serif;color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0)"><b>To:
</b></span><span style=3D"font-family:-webkit-system-font,Helvetica Neue,He=
lvetica,sans-serif">&quot;<a href=3D"mailto:tech@gmail.com" target=3D"_b=
lank">tech@gmail.com</a>&quot; &lt;<a href=3D"mailto:tech@gmail.com" =
target=3D"_blank">tech@gmail.com</a>&gt;<br>
</span></div>
<br>
<div>
<div style=3D"font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-v=
ariant-caps:normal;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:normal;text-align:start;t=
ext-indent:0px;text-transform:none;white-space:normal;word-spacing:0px;text=
-decoration:none">
<div style=3D"margin:0cm;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif"><sp=
an>=C2=A0</span></div>
<div style=3D"margin:0cm;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif"><sp=
an>=C2=A0</span></div>
<div style=3D"border-width:1pt medium medium;border-style:solid none none;b=
order-color:rgb(225,225,225) currentcolor currentcolor;padding:3pt 0cm 0cm"=
>
<div style=3D"margin:0cm;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif"><b>=
<span lang=3D"EN-US">From:</span></b><span lang=3D"EN-US"><span>=C2=A0</spa=
n>Go Receive &lt;<a href=3D"mailto:receive@Go.com.au" target=3D"_blan=
k">receive@Go.com.au</a>&gt;<br>
<b>Sent:</b><span>=C2=A0</span>Wednesday, 31 July 2024 9:36 AM<br>
<b>To:</b><span>=C2=A0</span>Bondi Go &lt;<a href=3D"mailto:Go.bon@bj=
chealth.com.au" target=3D"_blank">Go.bon@bgmail.com</a>&gt;<br>
<b>Subject:</b><span>=C2=A0</span>From: 61 2 9300 9218, you have received a=
 3 page fax on: 291693497 from Remote ID 13055037548</span></div>
</div>
<div style=3D"margin:0cm;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif">=C2=
=A0</div>
<p><br>
Inbound Fax Received<br>
Received at: 31-07-2024-09:35:48<br>
From: 61 2 9300 9218<br>
Remote Fax ID: 13055037548<br>
FaxID: 64235128<br>
On Fax Number: 291693497<br>
Pages: 3<br>
Transmission Result: COMPLETE<br>
Speed: 9600<br>
Connection Time: 113</p>
</div>
</div>
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div style=3D"line-break:after-white-space">
<div>
<blockquote type=3D"cite">
<div></div>
</blockquote>
</div>
<br>
</div>
</div>

</div><br clear=3D"all"><div><br></div><span class=3D"gmail_signature_prefi=
x">-- </span><br><div dir=3D"ltr" class=3D"gmail_signature" data-smartmail=
=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><font size=3D"-1" style=3D"color:rgb(=
136,136,136)"><span style=3D"vertical-align:baseline;font-size:12px;font-fa=
mily:Arial;background-color:transparent"><b>Igor Steblii</b></span></font><=
font size=3D"-1" style=3D"color:rgb(136,136,136)"><br></font><br><div><a hr=
ef=3D"http://igorsteblii.com" target=3D"_blank">igorsteblii.com</a><br></di=
v></div></div></div>

--000000000000c4fbc7062271c50a--
--000000000000c4fbc8062271c50c
Content-Type: application/pdf; 
    name="291693497-2024-07-31-093548-64235128.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename="291693497-2024-07-31-093548-64235128.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <19208a4c905d7a58eae1>
X-Attachment-Id: 19208a4c905d7a58eae1
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--000000000000c4fbc8062271c50c--



I parse it with a code, like:
import os
import base64
import email

msg = email.message_from_string(raw_string)

def extract_email_info(msg):
    # Extract basic email details
    email_data = {
        'sender': msg.get('From', 'Unknown Sender'),
        'recipient': msg.get('To', 'Unknown Recipient'),
        'subject': msg.get('Subject', 'No Subject'),
        'date': extract_date(msg),
        'body_plain': None,
        'attachments': [],
    }

    for part in msg.walk():
        process_part(part, email_data)

    # Ensure plain text body has a fallback message
    if not email_data['body_plain']:
        email_data['body_plain'] = "No plain text content found"
    
    return email_data


def process_part(part, email_data):
    content_type = part.get_content_type()
    disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition", ""))

    if content_type == "message/rfc822":
        forwarded_msg = email.message_from_bytes(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        extract_email_info(forwarded_msg)  # Process forwarded message

    elif content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in disposition:
        if not email_data['body_plain']:
            email_data['body_plain'] = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode(part.get_content_charset() or 'utf-8')

    elif part.get_filename() or "attachment" in disposition or content_type.startswith('application/'):
        attachment = {
            'file_name': part.get_filename() or "unnamed_attachment",
            'content_type': content_type,
            'data': part.get_payload(decode=True),
            'content_id': part.get('Content-ID'),
        }
        email_data['attachments'].append(attachment)


I also want to parse the email from where it was forwarded, as I automatically set forwarding on my email client. Forwarded emails might also have attachments I want to process.

you're importing base64 but not using it?

You said "I could not extract the base64 attachment".  Why?  What actually happens?  Is there an error?

Could you please specify what types are these parameters that you pass in the function process_part(part, email_data)?
Also what is the actuall error you get, and why you don't use base64 to decode the data if you want to do it?.

Thanks for the comments, I parse the email as msg = email.message_from_string(raw_string).

Base64 it attached to the end of the email, but when I go through the msg.walk() there is no Content. Disposition -> Attachment.

I updated with a full email text including sender and other metadata, seems like email. message_from_string cannot parse attachments?

There is a formatting problem in your sample email.  The 7th continuation line of the DKIM header starts in column 1, which is invalid.  If I indent that line, your code works perfectly for me.  I get the PDF.

Thanks, Tim, can you please share the exact line? (copy-paste)
